# .NET Core Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

So we have one main application and then another smaller one that needs only to read from two tables from database. My question is: do I still need to implement all the models for each table or am I good just with the 2 I actually need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just the 2 models you need. Consider creating a shared library that both applications can use.